# Generating HTML report of testcases results in SoapUI

Tags: ant, soapui, web-api-testing

I have an testsuite of API testing in SOAP UI.

I want an HTML report of testcases results. I am using basic SOAP UI version. Give me a solution apart from SOAP UI Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to generate Junit Style HTML reports using SoapUI Opensource Edition as well.

All you need to do is the execution of tests has to be done

- use `Apache-Ant` software, more details on installing and configuring [here](https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/)
- write build script

Here is the *sample build script*(build.xml):

Note that modify the SOAPUI_HOME(or define environment variable), soapui project file path, results directory path according to your environment.

```xml
<project basedir="." default="testreport" name="ant script for testing soapui project">
   <property environment="env"/>
   <property name="soapui.project" value="/app/demo-soapui-project.xml"/>
   <property name="results.dir" value="/tmp/results"/>
   <property name="reports.dir" value="${results.dir}/Reports"/>
   <property name="html.dir" value="${reports.dir}/html"/>
   <target name="execute.project">
     <exec dir="${env.SOAPUI_HOME}" executable="testrunner.sh">
        <arg line="-raj -f ${results.dir} ${soapui.project}" />
     </exec>
  </target>
   <target name="testreport" depends="execute.project">
    <mkdir dir="${reports.dir}"/>
          <junitreport todir="${reports.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${results.dir}">
               <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${html.dir}" />
         </junitreport>
   </target>
</project>
```

and execute following command (run soapui project and generate report):

```
ant
```

There is also simple way (i.e., every thing configured and readily available envrionment) if you are willing to use this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nmrao/soapui/).

Short video also available [there](https://asciinema.org/a/15b3ubalcmm4l4gcroqtsvpvh) on how to.